# Extract the pvalue and statistic from anova after looping

Tags: r, loops, anova

After trying th following code for a large dataframe

```
result <- list()
for(i in index:ncol(data)){

print(i)
tryCatch({

ind <- !(is.na(data[,i]))
fit <- aov(data[ind,i] ~ Gender[ind]+Age[ind]+Group[ind])
result <- rbind(result,summary(fit))
names <- c(names,rep(colnames(data)[i]))
   
},
error=function(cond) { print(cond)
}
)}
```

I got a list of 75 dataframe, 4 rows x 5 columns, I need the details of "Group" variable rbinded together in a dataframe. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `anova(fit)` as opposed to `summary(fit)`. `anova()` gives a dataframe as an output which is better suited to your aims here I think

Here is an example I made using the same dataframe repeatedly

```
for( i in 1:20){
  
  fit = aov(data1 ~data2+data3, mydf)
  my_anova_table=anova(fit)
  
  if (i==1)
  {
  result=my_anova_table[2,]
  rownames(result)[1]='trial 1'
  
  } else {
  result=rbind(result,my_anova_table[2,])
  rownames(result)[i]=paste0('trial ',i)
  }
}
```

The result is a data frame with the anova summary table row for my data3 variable. I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Thank you! I used do.call() to extract them as dataframe then filtered by "group". I appreciate your help!!